# Take a picture on Lightroom for iOS with an Apple Watch 4

Tags: photos, software-recommendation, apple-watch, adobe-lightroom

I like how Apple wrote an app on the watch that takes pictures with the native camera on iPhone.

In fact, would like to take RAW pictures with any iOS app like Lightroom or another that permits forcing a raw image capture.

I have an iPhone 6S Plus with iOS 14.0.1.

Do any apps have this feature for taking raw photos outside the native camera app for iOS?